¿ Tengo una maquina virtual con un MS2 y no consigo instalar un programa .exe / o no consigo transformar el .exe en .iso?
Como consigo transformar el archivo, del .exe al .iso, y porque no lo reconoce, porque no consigo encontrar la ruta desde el disco de almacenamiento que no me aparece la carpeta que he creado en la maquina virtual
